# issue customizing UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I'm using the following code to just make a single UILabel on my cell. (I know this example is contrived; I can't even get this to work much less my ultimate design goal.)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photo";

    UILabel *username;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

        username = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 20.0)];
        username.tag = USERNAME_TAG;
        username.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        username.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        username.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        username.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:username];
    } else {
        username = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:USERNAME_TAG];
    }

    //NSDictionary *photos = [self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    username.text = @"Testing!";

    return cell;
}
```

I got this template code from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)

However, when I run the code, there is no text label in the cell, but the accessory does show up.

Comment: Does `cellForRowAtIndexPath` even get called?

Comment: Yes, I just added `cell.textLabel.text = @"stupid";` below `cell.username.text = @"Testing!";` and it worked.

Comment: Is there by any chance a `UITableViewCell` in your xib/storyboard that the table is loaded from with the cell identifier Photo?  If so, the `if (cell == nil) {` code will never be called.

Comment: ugh you're exactly right. why did apple write the doc like that...? seems like it will never work? add an answer and i will give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple changed the behavior of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` when they released 5.0.

In 5.0+ it is guaranteed to always return a copy of your cell (if it exists in your xib/storyboard), even if you haven't even loaded a cell yet.  Prior to this, it would return a cell **only** if there was one that was ready to be recycled.

Because of this, some older code which assumes that you will receive nil unless you have already initialized it will break.

So, get rid of the identifier (or the entire cell) in your xib/storyboard or modify your logic so that it initializes it when needed (perhaps based on whether or not there is a view with the specified tag).

Answer (score 1):

I find it much easier to use a custom xib for table cells that don't lend themselves easily to one of the normal types. The basic steps are: create a xib with your row, create an outlet property, then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, call loadNibNamed and assign it to a local variable (that you return), and set the outlet back to nil.

The secret is that loading a nib with a nil outlet causes the nil outlet to be init'd and inflated with the contents of the nib.

Described here (scroll to Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files): 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

If you need a lot of user interaction, you are probably better off sub-classing UITableViewCell and supplying it with its own xib. If you have a lot of controls on a cell, you will end up using tags to determine the source of events, which gets messy with more than a few tags.

Comment: +1 I agree with putting this in a xib instead of laying it out programatically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to add a "standard" `UILabel` to the `UITableViewCell`.

Here's what you do: every `UITableViewCell` of the `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` has a property called `textLabel`. In your code, do the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photo";

    UILabel *username;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Testing!";

    return cell;
}
```

PS: Looks like you're trying to add an image at some point? There's a property for that as well. Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the `imageView` property.

Comment: ultimately, i need something much more complex than what the default `UITableViewCell` has. To be more specific, I will ultimately have 3 `UILabels`, a `UITextView` and a `UIImage`. I need to place them manually as well to get the UI i want. So I cant use the default properties. I made this example contrived just to get the point across; I need to be able to set up a single UILabel before I can do the rest.

Comment: In that case, you might want to create a custom UITableViewCell subclass, and layout your subviews there. Give each label a property that can be accessed by the UITableView that's rendering the cell, and leave the layout to the subclass. That'll let you use this cell in multiple places, and keep your UITableViewDelegate code clean.

Also, why the vote down?